# F# and Winforms

Tags: winforms, graphics, f#

i have a program like this

```
let form = new Form()
let drawArea = new Panel(Location = new Point(200,0), Height = 600, Width = 800)
let rectBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue)
form.Controls.Add(drawArea)

drawArea.MouseClick.Add(fun args -> 
    drawArea.Paint.Add(fun e -> 
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(rectBrush, args.X, args.Y, 50, 50)))

Application.Run(form)
```

so when i click a blue rectangle appears. However, where are these rectangles stored? is there any way to retrive a list of all the rectangles being part of the "drawArea"?

Otherwise, is there a way to add rectangles as child controllers to a panel or simular winform object?

Thank you

Comment: Ugh, every mouse click adds a new Paint event handler.  No, you can't retrieve the rectangles as written.  Just have the MouseClick handler add a rectangle to a list.  And call form.Invalidate to trigger a repaint, something that's not working now.  And use *one* Paint event handler that iterates that list.

Comment: BTW, the reason behind this is that Winforms uses "immediate mode" drawing. Other frameworks, like WPF, use retained mode, i.e. they explicitly store the visible structures for later reuse. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff684178(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: aha! thanks for the information, didn't know forms used immediate mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to retrieve these rectangles that way.

The best you can do is make a Rectangle class, and make it inherit from Control or UserControl. Then override it's protected OnPaint(...) method. For example:

```
public class FilledRectangle : UserControl
{
     private readonly float x, y, w, h;
     // also the brush here

     public FilledRectangle(float x, float y, float w, float h)
     {
          this.x = x;
          // ...
     }

     protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) // not sure about the event args type name
     {
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(this.myBrush, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
     }
}
```

Now you can simple add an object of this type to the Controls collection like so:

```
Controls.Add(new FilledRectangle(...));
```

With this approach you can easily create a collection of the rectangle objects and make them behave like you want them to.

Note that the examples I wrote above are in C#, but it shouldn't be too difficult to port it to F#. Only reason I'm not doing it is because I'm not very familiar with its syntax. Your question is not F#-specific, but .NET-specific.

Also note that as it has been commented by Hans, the Paint event won't fire until you call Invalidate().

Comment: Thanks for this information, this might be the way to go. Your answear + the comments has satisfied my needs.